# Prove that $C(x+y,y)$ is compositive number if $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}_{>1}^{+}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that $$x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, x,y>1 \implies  \binom{x+y}{y} \quad \text{is compositive.}$$

**My approach:** Let $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $x,y>1$ so we need to prove that $\binom{x+y}{y}$ is compositive. Now, since that $$\binom{x+y}{y}=\frac{(x+y)!}{x!(x+y-x)!}=\frac{(x+y)!}{x!y!}$$
Now, we can see that $\displaystyle \frac{(x+y)!}{x!y!}$ is compositive if $x!y!| (x+y)!$, but how can I continue from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that we have:
$${{x+y} \choose y}>1 $$
since $x,y>1$. Assuming the contrary, let ${{x+y} \choose y}=p$ where $p$ is a prime. Since $p \mid (x+y)!$, we must have $p \leqslant (x+y)$. Thus, we have:
$${{x+y} \choose y} \leqslant x+y \implies (x+y-1)! \leqslant x!y!$$
$$(x+y-1)! \leqslant (2 \cdot 3 \cdots x)(2\cdot3\cdots y)$$
$$(x+y-1)! < (2 \cdot 3 \cdots x)((x+1)\cdot(x+2)\cdots (x+y-1))$$
$$(x+y-1)!<(x+y-1)!$$
which is a contradiction. Hence, ${{x+y} \choose y}$ is a composite number.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank so much!